# Isolating a line from a polygon and measuring its length

Tags: r, spatial

I am trying to measure the length of a coastline. This will be used as a metric for position along a coastline in an analysis. For example, imagine I have data on the location of all public beaches in a region, and I want to describe how they are distributed in space by measuring their distance from a reference point on the coast.

I have followed [this extremely helpful tutorial](https://rspatial.org/cases/2-coastline.html) on calculating the length of a coastline using rulers of different lengths. However, it is only accurate if you want to measure the entire polygon length, that is, the geographic object you are interested in is an island.

To get a shapefile of a coastline (note that in the `ne_countries` call I am using a coarse scale on purpose, to make the coastline smoother, and only keeping the first shape returned--the "scalerank" name is not important):

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
basemap <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "united states of america", returnclass = "sf")[1]
bbox <- extent(-82, -65, 27, 35) 
cropmap <- st_crop(basemap, bbox)
plot(cropmap)
```

[image]

This returns a shape showing the South Atlantic coast down into Florida. However, if I measure the length of this shape, it will include all sides of the polygon--not just the coastline. How do I isolate the coastline (see below for a map of what part of the polygon is actually coastal) and just measure its length in R?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=basemap) +
  geom_sf(data=cropmap, color="blue", fill="blue")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a version similar to Robert's, staying in `sf`. I converted the original basemap from polygons to lines and then "cut out" the `bbox` like you did. Then you can just measure with `st_length`.

```
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
basemap <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "united states of america", returnclass = "sf")[1]
```

Convert from polygon to lines to avoid the parts of the polygon you don't want

```
basemap_lines <- basemap %>% st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")
plot(basemap_lines)
```

[Basemap as multilinestring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaE9p.png)
Then create the cookie cutter polygon, setting the `crs` to lat/lon

```
xmin <- -82
xmax <- -65
ymin <- 27
ymax <- 35
bbox <- st_polygon(list(rbind(c(xmin,ymin), c(xmin,ymax), c(xmax,ymax), c(xmax,ymin),c(xmin,ymin)))) %>% st_sfc()
st_crs(bbox) <- 4326
```

Then just crop with `st_intersection`

```
crop_lines <- st_intersection(basemap_lines, bbox)
plot(crop_lines)
st_length(crop_lines)
```

[Cropped line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRBHO.png)

For your `bbox` dimensions I get 1162849 meters (~723 miles), which aligns with the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty easy if you transform the polygons to lines before the cropping

Example data

```
library(raster)
library(rnaturalearth)
m <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "united states of america", returnclass = "sp")
ext <- extent(-82, -65, 27, 35)
```

Transform and crop

```
m <- as(m, "SpatialLines")   
croplines <- crop(m, ext)
```

Because the CRS is longitude/latitude, use geosphere, not rgeos, to compute the length

```
library(geosphere)
lengthLine(croplines)
#[1] 1162849
```

(i.e. 1162.8 km)

In some cases you may need intersect with a polygon instead of an extent (see `raster::drawPoly` and `raster::intersect`) or perhaps use `crop`, `disaggregate`, and visually `select` to get the lines you want.